# getting error in check constraint with modulus operator

Tags: mysql

I am implementing a check constraint on a column such that the inserted value is always a multiple of 11, which is below:

```
create table multinum(empid int(4) primary key, check (empid%11==0));
```

But I am getting the error

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '==0))' at line 1
```

So I removed one equal operator but now it is accepting those values as well that are not multiple of 11, like 12.

What is the problem in my statement? Is there any other way of doing this?

**EDIT**

I also tried below statement, but to no effect:

```
create table multinum(empid int(4) primary key check (empid%11==0));
```

Comment: In MySQL, equality operator is `=`, not `==`

Comment: I have already mentioned that. Please have a look, it is not working too.

Answer (score 0):

IT works just fine.

Copy the text from the example and try it in your database

CHECK constraints only work with mysql 8 prior versions didn't implement it completely.

> ```
> create table multinum(empid int(4) primary key, check (empid%11=0));
> ```

> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO multinum VALUES(10);
> ```
>
> ```
> Check constraint 'multinum_chk_1' is violated.
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO multinum VALUES(11);
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO multinum VALUES(22);
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO multinum VALUES(12);
> ```
>
> ```
> Check constraint 'multinum_chk_1' is violated.
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=91d7c690146481ae5e771b89f3d19279)*